# How to create toggle button for Macro

Tags: vba, outlook

I have created a macro that will set the categories of out going mail without needing to open the tag dialog. I have added the macro to the ribbon via the "Customize Ribbon" options on outlook itself. That macro works fine, however I would like the button to be highlighted (toggled on) when the category is set and then regular (toggle off) when the category is no longer set.

I only have basic VB knowledge but have good knowledge of java so the concepts are familiar just not the syntax. This is also the first macro I've ever done.

I have tried searching Google and Stack for an answer but I think due to my lack of knowledge I'm not using the correct keyword to get a useful result.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

VBA macros don't allow creating a custom ribbon UI. You need to develop a COM add-in if you want to customize the Fluent UI by adding a toggle button to the Outlook window.

Take a look at the following articles to create a custom ribbon UI:

- [Walkthrough: Create a custom tab by using the Ribbon Designer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-tab-by-using-the-ribbon-designer?view=vs-2019)
- [Walkthrough: Create a custom tab by using Ribbon XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-tab-by-using-ribbon-xml?view=vs-2019)

The Fluent UI is described in depth in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12))
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12))
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12))